# Questions related to the GIS extension and the use of Arithmetic Operators at NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

I have the following doubt. I have two files in .asc. I used the GIS extension to import the rasters into NetLogo version 6.2. I asked that the values ​​of veg <= 0.2 have the color gray + 4 (low values).

However, when inspecting some patches with gray + 4 color, the veg values > 0.2 values ​​appear (see picture). What am I doing wrong in the code? can anybody help me?

[image]

Bellow my code:

```
extensions [ gis ]

globals
[
  edge-size
  veg
  veg-2
]
patches-own
[
  veg-values
  veg-2-values
]

to setup
  clear-all
  set edge-size 300
  resize-world 0 edge-size 0 edge-size
  setup-layers
  create-turtles 15
  reset-ticks
 end

to setup-layers ;; load in the GIS data
  set veg gis:load-dataset "./layers/veg.asc"
  set veg-2 gis:load-dataset "./layers/veg2.asc"
  gis:set-world-envelope gis:envelope-of veg
  gis:apply-raster veg veg-values
  gis:set-world-envelope gis:envelope-of veg-2
  gis:apply-raster veg-2 veg-2-values
  color-veg
  color-veg-2
end

to color-veg
  ask patches [
    if veg-values <= 0.2 [ set pcolor gray + 4 ] ;; low values
    if veg-values > 0.2 [ set pcolor green - 4 ] ;; high values
  ]
 end

 to color-veg-2
   ask patches [
    if veg-2-values <= 0.2 [ set pcolor gray + 4 ] ;; low values
    if veg-2-values > 0.2 [ set pcolor green - 4 ] ;; high values
   ]
end
```

Thanks all!

Comment: first you set the patch colour using the value of veg-values, then you overwrite it immediately with a colour based on the variable veg-2-values. Which variable are you wanting to use to set the patch colour?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't quite understand your suggestion. Please, could you explain it better?

I would like to color the two files in .ascii (which is veg and veg-2) for that I created two variables one veg-values ​​for veg and another variable (veg-2-values) for veg-2. Do you understand? Thanks so much for your help :)

Comment: I can use veg-values to use to set the patch colour. If I use veg-values, Do I need to write 
    ask patches [ set pcolor veg-values ]?

Comment: @JenB Sorry, I didn't quite understand your suggestion. Please, could you explain it better? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your procedure to set up the patches looks like this:

```
to setup-layers ;; load in the GIS data
  ; ... multiple lines to assign values to patches from GIS data
  color-veg 
  color-veg-2
end
```

So it uses the GIS data to give two values to each patch, one for the variable 'veg-values' and one for the variable 'veg-2-values'. Then it calls the procedure 'color-veg' which colours the patches based on the value of 'veg-values'. It then immediately calls the procedure to colour the patch based on the value of 'veg-2-values'.

This means that at the end of the procedure, the patch will be coloured by the value of 'veg-2-values'. The patch has two variables, but the 'veg-2-values' is the one being used to colour it.